# Upload File with Java

Tags: java, applet

Is it possible to upload a text file using form submit or with ftp but without any 3rd party library?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Third-party libraries just make it (a lot) easier.

Comment: Many details missing. An actual file from the file system, or just the contents of a file? To what sort of server? Is the applet signed?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<input type="file" name="somename">
```

to your form.